# COALESCE with Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive

Since there is no `IFNULL`, `ISNULL`, or `NVL` function supported on Hive, I'm having trouble converting NULL to 0.  I tried `COALESCE(*column name*, 0)` but received the below error message:

> Argument type mismatch 0: The expressions after COALESCE should all
>   have the same type: "bigint" is expected but "int" is found

How to resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried `COALESCE(column,CAST(0 AS BIGINT))`?

Comment: Hive 0.11 onward, It has now NVL function. Please see
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Lamak pointed out in the comment, `COALESCE(column, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))` resolves the error.

Answer (score 49):

Hive supports [bigint literal since 0.8 version](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2509). So, additional "L" is enough:

```
COALESCE(column, 0L)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since [0.11 hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) has a NVL function 
`nvl(T value, T default_value)`

which says 
    *Returns default value if value is null else returns value*

Answer (score 5):

From [Hive Language Manual][1]:

> COALESCE (T v1, T v2, ...)

Will return the first value that is not NULL, or NULL if all values's are NULL

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions

Answer (score 4):

If customer primary contact medium is email, if email is null then phonenumber, and if phonenumber is also null then address. It would be written using COALESCE as

```
coalesce(email,phonenumber,address)
```

while the same in hive can be achieved by chaining together nvl as

```
nvl(email,nvl(phonenumber,nvl(address,'n/a')))
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Language DDL & UDF of Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

```
NVL(value, default value)
```

Returns default value if value is null else returns value

Answer (score 2):

```
nvl(value,defaultvalue) as Columnname
```

will set the missing values to defaultvalue specified